# SQL Server Browser won't start

Tags: sql, sql-server, service, spn

I want to start playing around with databases in Java to help with my university work however I can't get SQL Server to work properly. I've installed it using the wizard and selecting 'Basic' the installing SSMS. However when launching SSMS I get Error 26. When researching this it says to make sure that the SQL Server Browser service is running. Unfortunately this is the issue, every time I try to start the service it fails.

All the fixes I've seen about this topic have been related to servers on another machine where as I am trying to run the server on my own PC. I've tried them anyway but nothing has worked so far. The only thing I can find that might give you a clue in helping me is that in the log file it says that it failed to register the SPN.

Answer (score 1):

When working on my local machine, I don't usually need SQL Server browser - but my SQL Server itself isn't set up to run automatically.

You can go to services (either via window and search for 'services', or in Windows 10 open the task manager, go to the last tab 'services'). Find the 'SQL Server' service (it helps to sort by description column) and right click -> start.

If you take note of the name (default is 'MSSQLSERVER') you can start the service (e.g., in a batch file, from command line) using `sc start "MSSQLSERVER"` (or whatever your server instance is called).

Comment: My 'SQL Server' is setup to run automatically at the moment. I've tried restarting it and that didn't help :/

Comment: OK... I'm sorry - I'm out of answers then. I'll leave this here to show people that this isn't the answer.